# Get values in list equal to specific conditions

Tags: r

Is there a way to get values from list that is equal to specific values. Example

```
asd <- list(colb = structure(list(CNT = 1:3), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,3L)), cola = structure(list(CNT = 1L), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), colc = structure(list(CNT = 2L), class = "data.frame", row.names = 2L))
```

Here I need to get only `cola` since it has 1 row and the value is equal to 1.
So basically the condition is the element value should be equal to 1 and has only 1 row

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Filter` on your conditions, i.e.

```
Filter(length, lapply(asd, \(i)which(nrow(i) == 1 & i$CNT == 1)))

#$cola
#[1] 1
```

Comment: Great answer! Following!

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve your problem:

```
Filter(function(x) nrow(x)==1 && all(x==1), asd)

$cola
  CNT
1   1
```

Comment: I tried but got ````Error: unexpected input in "Filter(\"````

Comment: I think that it's because you are using an older version of R. I modified to accomodate the code to an older version of R too. Let me know if it works now.

Answer (score 0):

A trick with `all.equal(..., check.attributes = FALSE)`:

```r
Filter(\(x) all.equal(x, 1, check.attributes = FALSE), asd)

# $cola
#   CNT
# 1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `keep`

```
library(purrr)
 keep(asd, ~ nrow(.x) == 1&&  1 %in% .x$CNT)
$cola
  CNT
1   1
```